# NTLMv2 authentication in java

Tags: java, authentication, windows-authentication, single-sign-on, ntlmv2

Is it possible to implement the `NTLMv2` authentication in a Java application.

I read somewhere that I can achieve this through the `JCIFS` library, but I am not able to get any examples for it.

I want to implement Single sign on using this.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this free Java NTLMv2 library / filter:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/ntlmv2auth/

It's based on code from the Liferay open-source portal.

Answer (score 0):

JCIFS does not fully upport NTLMv2. Jespa supports it, but it requires a license if your application has more than 25 users (or more than 1 installation). Httpclient version 4.2.3 + supports NTLMv2 out of the box (source: [Connecting to NTLMv2 from Java\httpclient 3\linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15409778/connecting-to-ntlmv2-from-java-httpclient-3-linux?rq=1)).