# Connecting to NTLMv2 from Java\httpclient 3\linux

Tags: java, authentication, httpclient, ntlm, ntlmv2

I am using MAC and LINUX, java6 and apache http-client 3.1 to connect to sharepoint with NTLM auth.

I connect to ntlm using http://jcifs.samba.org/ and it worked fine until I had to connect to NTLMv2.
I tried this  http://devsac.blogspot.com/2010/10/supoprt-for-ntlmv2-with-apache.html
 but it doesnt work for me with NTLMv2,

Is there any way to make my httpclient 3.1 connect to NTLMv2 ? if not, is there a way to connect java to NTLMv2 without httpclient?

thanks

Comment: btw, I make sure the sharepoint side is using NTLMv2 by checking the "require NTLMv2 session security" checkbox, according to http://www.websense.com/support/article/kbarticle/How-do-I-Check-NTLM-Version-for-XID-Compatibility

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found an answer,
httpclient version 4.2.3 + supports NTLMv2 out of the box

Comment: jespa is another library (not free) which connects java code to NTLMv2. I believe, Jespa is created by same guys who created jcifs/NTLM modules.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to connect to ntlm v2 using httpclient 3.1:
http://devsac.blogspot.com/2010/10/supoprt-for-ntlmv2-with-apache.html?showComment=1381849801529#c7263680121593236558

Btw - httpclient 4.x supports ntlm v2 out of the box.